# FreeType "generic" conflict with c++/cx keyword

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, freetype, c++-cx

I have a problem with putting c++ and c++/cx together. I need to use FreeType library, but they are using "generic" name for some variable. I also need to enable VC++ extensions because WinRT app, which causes name conflict (generic is keyword in c++/cx)

```
1>freetype2\include\freetype\freetype.h(1391): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
```

I only added freetype reference and aditional include directories to my project properties.

Is there some way to solve this case?
Thank you for your help :)
Tomas

Comment: How are you solve a /ZW option conflict for WinRT app ? Just rename *.c file to *.cpp ?

Comment: Hi - I found this question while hitting the exact same issue. Are you also trying to compile Freetype with /clr:pure? If so, did you succeed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use preprocessor to rename this keyword temporarily:

```
#define generic GenericFromFreeTypeLibrary
#include .... files from FreeTypeLibrary
#undef generic
```

This solution is not very nice but should work.

Comment: Could you give an explicit example of what should this look like? What do you mean by GenericFromFreeTypeLibrary?

Comment: `GenericFromFreeTypeLibrary` is just arbitrary created name - just to cause FreeTypeLibrary will use this name instead of generic - which is keyword in WinRT. You can use `ABRACADABRA` or whatever you want - assuming it will not cause any new conflicts...

Comment: Ok I thought I had to replace that thing with something else.