# error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I want to use boost library in my code, and I found an error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
```

And this error is coming from the boost/filesystem/path.hpp,

```
path generic() const
{
...
}
```

And I don't know how to solve it, I google it and it looks like I need to redefine it. But I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FreeType "generic" conflict with c++/cx keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122266/freetype-generic-conflict-with-c-cx-keyword)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting: `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED` in Visual Studio Preprocessor Definitions as you can see in the following image:

[image: Preprocessor Definitions configuration page in Visual Studio]